# How can I limit my time online?

Tags: macos, internet

I have a PowerPC G5 with OS 10.5.8. I'd like to be able to automatically disable my internet connection after a set amount of time of usage (1.5 hours, 2 hours, whatever), but keep all programs usable, so the parental controls that limit computer usage are no good.

I downloaded Freedom, but since it requires me to manually tell it when to disable the internet and for how long, it doesn't really work for my purposes.

However, if I could have it automatically run 1-2 hours after opening Safari/Firefox, that would work too.

Alternatively, is there any other software out there that could do this kind of thing? I am looking into Intego ContentBarrier and Time Sheriff. Has anyone used these?

Comment: Actually , Id like something that leaves my net connection on but disables the browser to all public sites.

Comment: Yeah, something that blocks port 80 would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476/) firefox extension.

> You can block sites within fixed time
>   periods (e.g., between 9am and 5pm),
>   after a time limit (e.g., 10 minutes
>   in every hour), or with a combination
>   of time periods and time limit (e.g.,
>   10 minutes in every hour between 9am
>   and 5pm). You can also set a password
>   for access to the extension options,
>   just to slow you down in moments of
>   weakness!
>
> The sites to block can be specified
>   using wildcards (e.g., *.somesite.com)
>   and exceptions (e.g.,
>   +allowme.somesite.com).

Comment: But then they'll just open up IE. Nice find though

Answer (score 0):

[Meetimer](http://meetimer.productivefirefox.com/) might fit your needs. [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/291405/track-browsing-habits-and-curb-procrastination-with-meetimer) suggested it a few years ago.

Comment: That's a neat application, but it only tells you how much time you've spent procrastinating... it doesn't actually disconnect you or put a hard limit on your online time. Thank you, though!

Comment: "The time you enjoy wasting is NOT WASTED TIME." << THIS. It's ok to be a workaholic.. but we'll die someday..and why don't waste time happily? :)

Answer (score -1):

Switch of your modem, and turn it back on when you have fully completed all your work. ;)

Comment: The whole point here is to have an automatic solution.